# Why is QT Creator Automatically Splitting my String While Reading the Data from a STM32 Microcontroller?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, stm32cubeide

I have been trying to send some temperature values read by 2 sensors connected to STM32 Microcontroller. I have already programmed the mc to send just 2 lines of temperature values (vertically and each time new value updating; see below) to the textEdit widget of QT Creator

22.05 °C

23.12 °C

However QT keeps splitting the string in different sizes.. sometimes I receive it fully but sometimes just parts of it. (like .05°C or just °C). I even tried sending a normal string like Test or Hello.. the same issue happens. The debug console also displays split data (like 'est' or sometimes just 't' for Test). I can't figure out why is this happening.

My QT code for reading values :

```
void MainWindow::readData()
{
    QByteArray data = COMPORT->readAll();
    qDebug() << "Received Data Size:" << data.size();

    // Convert the received data to QString
    //QString receivedData = QString::fromUtf8(data);
    QString receivedData = QString(data);
    ui->textEdit->clear();
    qDebug() << "Received Data:" << receivedData;
    ui->textEdit->setText(receivedData);

}
```

My simplest version of STM32 code looks like this :

```
char buffer [7];
if (input == '1')
{
sprintf (buffer, "Test")
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)buffer, strlen(buffer), 200);
}
```

Comment: What does your `Received Data Size` log line look like? I'd be willing to bet that's already less than the full string.

Comment: How is your application supposed to guess where a record ends, so that it only gives you complete records? You'll have to write that code yourself.

Comment: @Cubic, yes the received data size is also split (i was trying to send 6, but it splits as 1 and 5, or 2 and 3 etc) sometimes it does recieve the entire size 6 too.

Comment: `readAll()` will return whatever bytes are currently available in the incoming-bytes-buffer.  How many bytes are currently available depends on when you call `readAll()` compared to when the bytes were transmitted and received, so it can and will vary from moment to moment; in particular there is no guarantee that you will receive all the bytes of a given transmitted string within a single call.  What you can do is have your `readData()` slot add the received bytes to the end of an internal buffer, then examine that internal buffer to see if it contains "enough" bytes yet; if so, parse them.